# Using the Streampad API to pull the current song title

Tags: javascript, jquery, streampad

I can't figure out how to pull the song title from the Streampad API. This is straight from the [Streampad API website](http://www.streampad.com/javascript-api).

> `SPAPI.song():Object`
>
> Returns the current song that is
>   playing. Object will have these
>   properties: songTitle, artist, album,
>   imageUrl (link to album cover art),
>   sourceUrl (link to page containing
>   song), queue (number this song is in
>   the play queue).

using jQuery so far I have this..

```
$(".artist").click(function(){
    alert(SPAPI.song(songTitle));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.songTitle`](http://www.streampad.com/javascript-api) is a *property* on the returned object, so it's accessed like this:

```
$(".artist").click(function(){
    alert(SPAPI.song().songTitle);
});
```

For a bit of error checking, make sure there is a song, like this:

```
$(".artist").click(function(){
    var s = SPAPI.song();
    alert(s && s.songTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".artist").click(function(){
   alert(SPAPI.song().songTitle);
});
```